# How to display fixed frame of Cloudmade map?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, cloudmade

I need to display certain regeon in Cloudmade map. Currently I am getting the map and can view all the places of world by dragging the map. I want to display a certain place(frame) with fixed zoom so that only that part of map is displayed, something like a image in large scrollview. Also I need to place pins, so I cant use static images provided by Cloudmade or google [http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn%20Bridge,New%20York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel%3aS%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color%3agreen%7Clabel%3aG%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color%3ared%7Ccolor%3ared%7Clabel%3aC%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false).

How to do so?